# Passing multiple rails variables to javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rjs

I have some values in ruby (variables and objects / hash) that I want to pass on to javascript on the rendered page. Currently I use these methods to simply write the javascript of declaring the variables at the client end.

```
  def declare_as_js_vars vars
    string = ""
    vars.each do |name, value|
      string += self.declare_as_js_var(name, value)
    end
    string
  end

  def declare_as_js_var name, value
    name.to_s + "='" + value.to_s + "';"
  end
```

The problem here is that I am unable to declare objects, and have to declare vars individually. I was wondering if there is some way in rails to easily do this because this is turning out to be quite a hack.

How should I pass variables and objects to javascript? Please provide some syntax example

Comment: Related: stackoverflow.com/questions/2464966/passing-ruby-variables-to-javascript-function-in-rails-view

Answer (score 10):

It' s a bit late but maybe it will help the others. There is a nice gem called [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) which is very useful with passing variables from rails to javascript. You can also send the whole object.

In the controller you can have something like this

```
@your_int = 123
@your_array = [1,2]
@your_hash = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2}
gon.your_int = @your_int
gon.your_other_int = 345 + gon.your_int
gon.your_array = @your_array
gon.your_array << gon.your_int
gon.your_hash = @your_hash
gon.your_object = Table.find(params[:id])
```

then in the javascript it will be available like

```
alert(gon.your_int)
alert(gon.your_other_int)
alert(gon.your_array)
alert(gon.your_hash)
alert(gon.your_object.name)
```

There is also a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript) about it.

Answer (score 9):

I like to use script tags of type JSON to get the job done. It avoids polluting the global namespace and Rails happens to have great support for serializing objects to JSON.

You might use something like this in you view:

```
<script id="my_vars_json" type="text/json">
    <%= @my_vars.to_json %>
</script>
```

Then it's up to you to parse the JSON with JavaScript. I like to use jQuery:

```
$(function () {

    var myVarsJSON = $("#my_vars_json").html(),
        myVars     = $.parseJSON(myVarsJSON);

    console.log(myVars);

});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I had trouble with this approach when `@my_vars` represented multiple entires from a database (e.g., @my_vars = MyVar.all in the controller, where MyVar is a model). Using `<%= raw @my_vars.to_json %>` remedied the issue. Thanks for your answer, it was helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I needed to get user's first name from database and pass the value to a javascript variable in JSON format.

I then declared a `ruby` variable named token which takes `id` and `firstname` attribute from the user table,

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false

  @token = User.all.to_json(only: [:id, :firstname])
```

In the `erb` file, I used the following line,

```
var tokenList = <%= @token.html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using [Gon gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/gon) will be the best solution.
also check out this [video casts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to work with objects.to_json ;)

Answer (score 0):

i found that gem [client variable](https://github.com/coffa/client_variable), it look promising. your configuration and variable are pass to client and you can easy get or set in client

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this.

http://tech.thereq.com/post/17243732577/rails-3-using-link-to-remote-true-with-jquery-ujs

One of the easiest ways is to use js.erb file, where you can do ruby tags to access variables that you defined in the controller action.

You need to use a respond_to block in the controller action, specifying the action to be able to respond to javascript.

**items_controller.rb**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  def action
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      #format.html {}    #  These are for allowing other types of formats to be responded to.
      #format.json {}    #  But they are not necessary for using this js.erb way of doing things.
    end
  end

end
```

**/views/items/action.js.erb**

```
$(div).html('The cat has erased your page');
```